Как использовать в этой реализации RetinaNet свои изображения?
Всем добрый день! Нашёл реализацию RetinaNet. Хочу адаптировать её под свои нужды, но для этого нужно понять как засунуть в неё свои изображения...
Помогите пожалуйста
Ссылка: https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/

по вашей же ссылке в самом конце в главе Generating detections вроде указано, как подгружать датасет.

Датасет, но не свои изображения

Решается так:
def prepare_image(image):
    image, _, ratio = resize_and_pad_image(image, jitter=None)
    image = tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input(image)
    return tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0), ratio

imag = keras.utils.load_img("test/ue.jpg") # подгружаем картинку
input_arr = keras.utils.img_to_array(imag) # конвертируем в массив

int2str = dataset_info.features["objects"]["label"].int2str

image = tf.cast(input_arr, dtype=tf.float32) # вставляем полученный массив
input_image, ratio = prepare_image(image)
detections = inference_model.predict(input_image)
num_detections = detections.valid_detections[0]
class_names = [int2str(int(x)) for x in detections.nmsed_classes[0][:num_detections]]
visualize_detections(image,detections.nmsed_boxes[0][:num_detections] / ratio,class_names,detections.nmsed_scores[0][:num_detections],)

Картинку с результатом прилагаю

